# Integrating with Hangouts via Smack 3.1.0 in Java

Tags: java, smack, google-talk

I am using smack 3.1.0 to attempt to connect to hangouts using XMPP. It connects successfully and I can attempt to send messages, but the participants of the chat never receive them.

```
ConnectionConfiguration xmppConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
connection = new XMPPConnection(xmppConfig);

connection.connect();

//SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0); Appears to not be needed
// Get data
String user = Controller.getSettings().USERNAME;
String password = Controller.getSettings().PASSWORD;
connection.login(user, password);
for (Object name : Controller.getSettings().USER_LIST.keySet().toArray()) {
        createAndAddToChat(name.toString());
        Chat chat = chat(name.toString());
        Message message = new Message(chat.getParticipant(), Message.Type.chat);
        message.setBody(Controller.getName() + " has activated on server : "
                        + Controller.getPluginInstance().getServer().getServerName());
        chat.sendMessage(message);
}
```